# php multidimensional array

Tags: php

I want to create a twodimensional array in php. What is the correct syntax of creating an empty multidimensional array in php.

Secondly I want to create 7 two dimensional array in for

Comment: All of the answers you've had give you at least an idea, but we're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Your question looks incomplete, but still, I have written an answer that will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the PHP online manual. The first example shows you how to create a multi dimensional array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

```
<?php
$twoDimensionalArray = array (
    "fruits"  => array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"),
    "numbers" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    "holes"   => array("first", 5 => "second", "third")
);
?>
```

To do what you want in a for loop, you can do so like this

```
// the following creates a 2d array. the first dimension contains 7 arrays of numbers 1 to 10
$firstDimension = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $firstDimension[] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some other langauges (such as standard C), arrays in PHP are "sparse" (i.e.: they only take up the space they need) so you can define a multi-dimensional array simply via:

```
$testArray = array();
```

(i.e.: You don't need to reserve the amount of space you're going to require.) However, more usefully, you can add values as follow:

```
$testArray = array();
$testArray[0][0] = "Hello";
$testArray[0][1] = "World";
...
```

That said, I'd recommend reading the [PHP array manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php), as you might want to use named indexes, etc. and it has better examples.

Comment: It really helped me..But how to create 7 twodimensional array in for loop with diffrent names

Comment: @Siddesh By reading the manual, understanding what it says and implementing it yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Multi-dimentional arrays are like regular arrays but the value to some (or all) or their keys are arrays.

For example you can create a two dimentional array like this:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[1] = array(1 => 'one', 2 => 'two');
```

And you can use it like this:

```
echo $arr[1][1]; //which prints "one"
```

Answer (score 0):

To create empty multidimensional array in PHP, you can do the following.

```
$arr_1 = array();
```

Yes. That's all. You can insert any type of data or array in it. There is no specific declaration of various arrays in PHP.
Now, suppose I want to insert data inside this multidimensional array $arr_1. I need to create an array of addresses. Each address item will have city, state and country.
You can do this as follows:

```
$arr_1[0] = array( 
  'city' => 'Gurgaon', 
  'state' => 'Haryana',
  'country' => 'India'
);
$arr_1[1] = array( 
  'city' => 'Los Angeles', 
  'state' => 'California',
  'country' => 'United States'
);
$arr_1[1] = array( 
  'city' => 'Melbourne', 
  'state' => 'Victoria',
  'country' => 'Australia'
);
```

You can create as many arrays as you want in this way.
If you want to learn more about PHP arrays (Indexed, Associative, Multidimensional), visit [PHP arrays explained with examples - Webolute Blog](https://webolute.com/blog/programming/php-arrays-explained-with-examples)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$twoDimensionalArray = array (
    "fruits"  => array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"),
    "numbers" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    "holes"   => array("first", 5 => "second", "third")
);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Nitesh, this is a 10 year old question that has been answer multiple times, also when posting code snippets put it between marks for formatting.